# GCC produces errors on valid stb_image.h

Tags: c, gcc, g++, gcc-warning, stb-image

Following shows two errors generated by GCC:

```
 In file included from /home/omar/Desktop/Lovelace/src/main.cpp:22:
         /home/omar/Desktop/Lovelace/include/stb/stb_image.h: In function ‘void* stbi__load_gif_main(stbi__context*, int**, int*, int*,
 int*, int*, int)’:
         /home/omar/Desktop/Lovelace/include/stb/stb_image.h:6778:11: **error: variable ‘out_size’ set but not used** [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
          6778 |       int out_size = 0;
               |           ^~~~~~~~
         /home/omar/Desktop/Lovelace/include/stb/stb_image.h:6779:11: **error: variable ‘delays_size’ set but not used** [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
          6779 |       int delays_size = 0;
               |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
         cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
         make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lovelace.dir/build.make:102: CMakeFiles/lovelace.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
         make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/lovelace.dir/all] Error 2
         make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Yet there doesn't seem to be any problem as the variables are indeed used:

```
  int out_size = 0;
  int delays_size = 0;
  memset(&g, 0, sizeof(g));
  if (delays) {
     *delays = 0;
  }

  do {
     u = stbi__gif_load_next(s, &g, comp, req_comp, two_back);
     if (u == (stbi_uc *) s) u = 0;  // end of animated gif marker

     if (u) {
        *x = g.w;
        *y = g.h;
        ++layers;
        stride = g.w * g.h * 4;

        if (out) {
           void *tmp = (stbi_uc*) STBI_REALLOC_SIZED( out, out_size, layers * stride );
           if (NULL == tmp) {
              STBI_FREE(g.out);
              STBI_FREE(g.history);
              STBI_FREE(g.background);
              return stbi__errpuc("outofmem", "Out of memory");
           }
           else {
               out = (stbi_uc*) tmp;
               out_size = layers * stride;
           }

           if (delays) {
              *delays = (int*) STBI_REALLOC_SIZED( *delays, delays_size, sizeof(int) * layers );
              delays_size = layers * sizeof(int);
           }
        } else {
           out = (stbi_uc*)stbi__malloc( layers * stride );
           out_size = layers * stride;
           if (delays) {
              *delays = (int*) stbi__malloc( layers * sizeof(int) );
              delays_size = layers * sizeof(int);
           }
        }      int out_size = 0;
```

Is this a compiler bug?

Edit: Version of GCC is 9.3.0

OS: Linux Mint latest

Comment: Not seeing it used.  I'd guess STBI_REALLOC_SIZED is a macro that doesn't use the old size parameter.

Comment: Do not seek problems in the compiler. The rule of thumb: 1. compiler is always right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code initialises and modifies `out_size`and `delay_size` but does not use them (they are only ever written, and never read).  The one place it *appears* to be used is the `STBI_REALLOC_SIZED()` calls, but `STBI_REALLOC_SIZED` is a macro defined thus:

```
#define STBI_REALLOC_SIZED(p,oldsz,newsz) STBI_REALLOC(p,newsz)
```

so `oldsz` is unused.

Compiling without `-Wunused-variable` (or one of the `-W` options that imply this) and  `-Werror` is an unsatisfactory solution as it will suppress warnings in your own code that you might want.  Had this been normal library code rather the static functions in a header (a nasty thing in itself), then you could compile the third-party code with different options that your own code.  The simplest solution is to modify the stb_image.h file such that it has:

```
int out_size = 0; out_size = out_size ;
int delays_size = 0; delays_size = delays_size ;
```

or

```
int out_size = 0; (void)out_size ;
int delays_size = 0; (void)delays_size ;
```

It turns out the header already has a macro for that:

```
int out_size = 0; STBI_NOTUSED(out_size) ;
int delays_size = 0; STBI_NOTUSED(delays_size) ;
```

That will "use" the variables in a manner that has no real effect and can be optimised out (though clearly that is not a concern if you choose to use this hideous abuse of a header file).  The dummy use suppresses the warning.

Ordinarily you might not want to change a header to a third-party library, but in this case the header *is* the library so there is no risk of inconsistency if say it weer a header for an shared object library. The change is visible to all code that uses it.  The only issue is that you might have to re-implement the fix if you adopt an updated version.  One solution to that is to submit a change request to the author, so the problem goes away for everyone.

Comment: Those two solutions are nasty but I don't want to turn off -Werror.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: They are not nasty, they are idiomatic - what is nasty is the idea of a single file library in a header-file!  This is the least of your worries.  It has the advantage of continuing to work if the realloc macro is changed to a version that uses old-size.  The macro has  a `#ifndef defined STBI_REALLOC_SIZED` wrapper so it can be overridden by an external definition, so you must maintain support for the unused argument.

Comment: I found out that someone already opened a pull request regarding this issue: https://github.com/nothings/stb/pull/1024/commits/f6523ac2a636af517060d31b5606ee3620cb49e9
But this was 5 months ago and it's still open.

Comment: Good spot - that STBI_NOTUSED macro already exists, so use that.  It wraps the solution I already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as by using `stbi__load_gif_main(...)`, warnings are generated. This isn't the compilers fault, nor is it yours.

I reproduced this and got the same results.

Without diving deeper in why, you could solve this by compiling **without** the flag `-Werror`.

Anyone who can fill in why the warnings are there in the first place, please do.

Comment: For now I'm going to use Clifford's solution as I don't want to turn off -Werror. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything what @Cliffort wrote in his answer is right but (using gcc) instead of `(void)` which is hard to search as it will also show functions with no parameters I would use

`int aUnused __attribute__((unused));` as when I see the code it is self explanatory and it is very easy to search.

(void) sometimes have some side effects like generating dead code for `(void)variable` if `variable` is `volatile`

https://godbolt.org/z/MrKW1d

Comment: The problem with `__attribute__((unused))` is 1) it is not portable, an the rest of tehi sfile has conditional compilation for MSC, 2) the variables concerned are initialised and I tried it and `int x = 0 __attribute__((unused)) ;` is invalid, so you would have to further change it to add an assignment after declaration.  The solution is to wrap the idiomatic `(void)x ;` in a macro.  It turns out that this code already has that in `STBI_NOTUSED(x)`.